# Locally compact and regular topogical space needs to be Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Consider X a topological space, that is locally compact and regular.
Is X necessarily a Hausdorff space?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, see for instance an indiscrete topological space with at least two points. However, a regular space is Hausdorff if and only if it's T0, regardless of local compactness.

Answer (score 1):

Any $T_0$ regular space is Hausdorff.  Given points $x, y\in X$ such that $x\ne y$, either $x$ is not in the closure of $\{y\}$, or vice versa.  In either case, due to regularity you can separate the points by disjoint open neighborhoods.

If you drop the $T_0$ assumption - it's possible to create artificial counter-examples.  Start from any locally compact regular Hausdorff space $X$, take some point $x_0$ in $X$, and double it by replacing it by two distinct points.  Now define the topology with the same open sets as before - either containing both points or containing neither point.  This topology doesn't differentiate between the two points in any way, and otherwise has the same properties as before.