# Why topological spaces in Baire category theorem are required to be Hausdorff?

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

In Baire category theorem it says  a locally compact Hausdorff space $S$ is second category.

In the proof, it choose $V_1,V_2\cdots$ are dense open subset of $S$. $B_0$ is an arbitrary nonempty open set in $S$. Then we choose $B_n\not = \emptyset$,$\bar B_n \subset V_n \cap B_{n-1}$. We can choose $\bar B_n$ is compact. Put $K=\cap_{n=1}^\infty \bar B_n$. Because in compact space, every family of closed subsets having the finite intersection property has non-empty intersection. So $K$ is nonempty. And $K\subset B_0,K\subset V_n$. Hence $B_0$ intersects $\cap V_n$

So where the Hausdorffness is used. It seems that it should only be regular space. So where it use that it should be regular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say: "We can find open $B_n$ with $\overline{B_n}\subseteq V_n\cap B_{n-1}$ such that $\overline{B_n}$ is compact". But why? Strong local compactness tells me that the open neighbourhood $V_n\cap B_{n-1}$ contains a compact neighbourhood $K$. That means, there is an open $B_n\subseteq K$. I would now love to conclude that $\overline{B_n}$ is also compact - but I can't! Not without further assumptions. If I assume the space is Hausdorff, then $K$ is closed, so $\overline{B_n}\subseteq\overline{K}=K$ and I get to conclude $\overline{B_n}$ is compact. It's worse than that, though: I need to also conclude $\overline{B_n}\subseteq V_n\cap B_{n-1}$. This is again easy if $K$ is closed, but it doesn't follow if $K$ is not closed (which is possible if the space is not Hausdorff).

If I'm not allowed to choose the $B_\bullet$ to be precompact, then the proof breaks down at the end. Specifically, I need to be able to conclude at least one $B_n$ has $\overline{B_n}$ compact.

---

Consider the example of John Doe. $X=\Bbb N$ with the cofinite topology and we define $V_n:=\Bbb N\setminus\{n\}$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. The closed sets are precisely the finite sets; an infinite set's closure is always $\Bbb N$ itself. So if I want $\overline{B_n}\subseteq V_n\cap B_{n-1}$ I must at least have every $B_n$ finite (then compactness would also follow nicely). But for $B_n$ to be open, it must be infinite. So I can actually never have a $B_n$ whose closure is (compact and) contained in $V_n$.

Comment: $V_n\cap B_{n-1}$ contains a compact neighborhood $K$. Does the space also need to be Hausdorff to get the conclusion?

Comment: @xyz It doesn’t *need* to be, allegedly regularity is enough, but if the space is Hausdorff then that’s strong enough to conclude what we want. The Hausdorff condition implies the compact neighbourhood is also closed, which is needed/useful for two reasons as I explained

Answer (score 7):

Consider $\Bbb{N}$ with the topology defined by a basis consisting of all co-finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$.  This topology is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.  Every point is closed.  Every non-empty open set is co-finite.  So the space is a countable union of closed sets with empty interior ($\{n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb{N})$.

The space is compact.  For any open cover - one member already covers all but finitely many points - and you can make a finite choice of sets to cover the remaining points.

Edit: To answer the questions in the last paragraph more thoroughly

1. It is enough to assume that $S$ is locally-compact regular.
2. Every locally-compact Hausdorff space is regular.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313688).
3. Every $T_0$ regular space is Hausdorff.  See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709496).
4. Where is regularity used?  Consider the induction step.  $B_{n-1}$ is a non-empty open set by the induction hypothesis.  $V_n$ is a dense open set by assumption.  Hence $\Gamma_n=V_n \cap B_{n-1}$ is non-empty and open.  Let $y\in \Gamma_n$.  By local compactness, there exists some compact set $D$ such that $y\in\operatorname{int}D$.  The set $\Delta_n=\Gamma_n\cap\operatorname{int}D$ is an open neighborhood of $y$.  By regularity, there is a closed set $C$ such that $y\in\operatorname{int} C \subseteq C\subseteq \Delta_n$.  Also $\Delta_n\subseteq D$ by definition.  Hence $C$ is a relatively-closed subset of the compact space $D$ - so $C$ is a closed compact neighborhood of $y$ and $C\subseteq\Delta_n\subseteq \Gamma_n$.  Now take $B_n=\operatorname{int}C$.

Comment: $y\in\operatorname{int} C \subseteq C\subseteq \Delta_n$. How it use regularity?

Comment: @xyz:  $S$ is regular, $S\setminus \Delta_n$ is closed and $y\not\in S\setminus \Delta_n$.  By regularity there are open sets $L, M$ such that $y\in L, S\setminus \Delta_n\subseteq M, L\cap M=\emptyset$.  Take $C=S\setminus M$.  Then $C$ is closed and $y\in L\subseteq C\subseteq \Delta_n$ so $y$ is an interior point of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

The Baire category theorem does hold for plenty of non-Hausdorff spaces. For example, it holds for all Quasi-Polish spaces (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.11.001).